# Manual alteration of RFLAGS register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, flags

According to Wikipedia, **RFLAGS** register, in x64 architecture, contains some special values, such as reserved ones and I/O privilege level. I was wondering if it possible to push the status register onto the stack, modify it and then popping it back.

I was also doubtful whether operating systems can prevent this, or if they allow this sort of tampering. I was thinking about something like this:

```
pushfq                 # pushing onto the stack
pop rax                # loading the value in rax
xor rax, 0xcafebabe    # performing some random operation
push rax               # pushing the brand new RFLAGS 
popfq                  # popping it back
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  However, if you change flags that are privileged while having insufficient privileges, the flags in question are not modified.  The exact rules are a bit complicated, refer to the [manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPF:POPFD:POPFQ.html) for details.