# Are there any internal descriptions of the RFLAGS 32-63 bits?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, flags, eflags

Searched the [Intel Manuals](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671200) but couldn't find any internal descriptions of the reserved `RFLAGS` 32-63 bits.

In this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KWcf9j177) demo, when executed in 64-bit mode, the output displays the current state of the `RFLAGS` register, with bits 32-63 set to 0.

```
Bit 0  - Carry Flag (CF): 0
Bit 1  - Reserved, always 1 in EFLAGS: 1
Bit 2  - Parity Flag (PF): 0
Bit 3  - Reserved: 0
Bit 4  - Adjust Flag (AF): 0
Bit 5  - Reserved: 0
Bit 6  - Zero Flag (ZF): 0
Bit 7  - Sign Flag (SF): 0
Bit 8  - Trap Flag (TF): 0
Bit 9  - Interrupt-enable Flag (IF): 1
Bit 10 - Direction Flag (DF): 0
Bit 11 - Overflow Flag (OF): 0
Bit 12 - I/O Privilege Level (IOPL) - low bit: 0
Bit 13 - I/O Privilege Level (IOPL) - high bit: 0
Bit 14 - Nested Task (NT): 0
Bit 15 - Mode flag (MD) - Reserved: 0

Bit 16 - Resume Flag (RF): 0
Bit 17 - Virtual 8086 Mode (VM): 0
Bit 18 - Alignment Check/Access Control (AC): 0
Bit 19 - Virtual Interrupt Flag (VIF): 0
Bit 20 - Virtual Interrupt Pending (VIP): 0
Bit 21 - ID Flag (ID): 0
Bit 22 - Reserved: 0
Bit 23 - Reserved: 0
Bit 24 - Reserved: 0
Bit 25 - Reserved: 0
Bit 26 - Reserved: 0
Bit 27 - Reserved: 0
Bit 28 - Reserved: 0
Bit 29 - Reserved: 0
Bit 30 - AES key schedule loaded flag (none): 0
Bit 31 - Alternate Instruction Set (AI): 0

Bit 32 - Reserved: 0
Bit 33 - Reserved: 0
Bit 34 - Reserved: 0
Bit 35 - Reserved: 0
Bit 36 - Reserved: 0
Bit 37 - Reserved: 0
Bit 38 - Reserved: 0
Bit 39 - Reserved: 0
Bit 40 - Reserved: 0
Bit 41 - Reserved: 0
Bit 42 - Reserved: 0
Bit 43 - Reserved: 0
Bit 44 - Reserved: 0
Bit 45 - Reserved: 0
Bit 46 - Reserved: 0
Bit 47 - Reserved: 0
Bit 48 - Reserved: 0
Bit 49 - Reserved: 0
Bit 50 - Reserved: 0
Bit 51 - Reserved: 0
Bit 52 - Reserved: 0
Bit 53 - Reserved: 0
Bit 54 - Reserved: 0
Bit 55 - Reserved: 0
Bit 56 - Reserved: 0
Bit 57 - Reserved: 0
Bit 58 - Reserved: 0
Bit 59 - Reserved: 0
Bit 60 - Reserved: 0
Bit 61 - Reserved: 0
Bit 62 - Reserved: 0
Bit 63 - Reserved: 0
```

**Modifying RFLAGS Test**

From [Manual alteration of RFLAGS register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763748/manual-alteration-of-rflags-register)

```
pushfq
pop     rax                     ; rax = 202
xor     rax,0FFFFFFFFCAFEBABEh  
push    rax                     ; rax = ffffffffcafeb8bc
popfq
pushfq
pop     rax                     ; rax = 200a96
```

After the `popfq` instruction, the lower 32-bits were modified (caused weird program behavior too) but the reserved upper 32-bits were unaffected.

As the answer notes:

> Those flags are reserved, and are always 0. Writing 1s into them is
> currently ignored - they stay zero anyway.

Comment: Yes, bits 32–63 of the flags are indeed all reserved.

Comment: You mean the upper bits of RFLAGS, that aren't part of EFLAGS?  Your question title asks about all the bits, and most of the low 32 (aka EFLAGS) are well documented.  I'm not aware of any 64-bit-only usage of bits in the upper 32, so for now those are still all just reserved.  (Intel has been pretty fanatical up until the recent APX about making all new extensions work in 32-bit as well as 64-bit mode, even though that means AVX-512 EVEX prefixes are longer or have fewer usable bits than they otherwise would, and encoding/decoding is more complicated with some bits inverted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those flags are reserved, and are always 0. Writing 1s into them is currently ignored - they stay zero anyway. It is possible, that those flags do not even exist in hardware.

Most likely, they were added to keep the stack 8 byte aligned when the CPU pushes RFLAGS in 64-bit mode. Future CPUs might find a use for those bits, so using them for some funny business is not recommended.

Comment: I wasn't able to verify if the RFLAGS 32-63 bits are always 0, although in my tests they were 0. Was curious if those undocumented reserved bits might be documented somewhere. ;) Thanks.